# Flutter - Getting HTTP Response from url_launcher

Tags: http, dart, flutter, http-status-codes

In Flutter it's easy to take the user to a website using [url_launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher) (**FIG A**). I'm looking for a way to return a HTTP status code upon completion / failure. This would ideally be returned in a string for text output.

FIG A;

```
_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://google.com/';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void _loadFromUrl(String url) async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {...}
  else {...}
```

I hope it'll help

Comment: I’ll get back to you on this ASAP. Thanks

Comment: This works! Thanks Andrey. One question though, how can I return the status code as a string? This is the kind of purpose I need it for: `print('All Good! This link returned status code' + response.statusCode);`

Comment: `print('All Good! This link returned status code ${response.statusCode}');`